# min{} in the integral

Tags: calculus

I actually don't know what min{} in the question means. After knowing that I think I can solve it out.

$$ Q.\qquad \int_0^{2\pi}\min \left\{  |x-\pi|, \cos^{-1}(\cos x) \right\} \,dx $$

Comment: Min{} = whichever the two functions within is smaller for that $x$

Comment: The Maple command $evalf(Int(min(abs(x-Pi), arccos(cos(x))), x = 0 .. 2*Pi)) $ produces $4.934802201$ and the one $identify(\%) $ gives $1/2\,{\pi }^{2}. $

Comment: After solving I got the answer to be (pi)^2 but in my book the correct option is given to be (pi)^2/2. Don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: What do the graphs of $\cos^{-1}(\cos x)$ and $|x-\pi|$ look like? Knowing that, what does the graph of their minima for each $x$ in $[0, 2\pi]$ look like?

Comment: Yeah, this is the way(graphing the functions) in which the solution is given in my solution booklet but I want to solve it in a different method. I spitted the integral into 0-pi and pi-2pi and found the min of the two functions and integrated. But at the end of the day my ans is wrong. Can you please show me the steps on how to do it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\min\{a,b,\ldots,c\}$ is the least element of the set $\{a,b,\ldots,c\}$. (A least element always exists because the set is finite).

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying each function, you have that
  $|x-\pi|= \begin{cases}
\pi-x,  & \text{if $0\le x\le\pi$} \\
x-\pi, & \text{if $\pi\le x\le2\pi$}  \\
\end{cases}$

and $\cos^{-1}(\cos x)=\begin{cases}
x, & \text{if $0\le x\le\pi$} \\
2\pi-x, & \text{if $\pi\le x\le2\pi$.}  \\
\end{cases}$

Therefore $\min\big\{|x-\pi|,\cos^{-1}(\cos x)\big\}= \begin{cases}
x, & \text{if $0\le x\le \frac{\pi}{2}$} \\
\pi-x, & \text{if $\frac{\pi}{2}\le x\le \pi$} \\
x-\pi, & \text{if $\pi\le x\le\frac{3\pi}{2}$} \\
2\pi-x, & \text{if $\frac{3\pi}{2}\le x\le 2\pi.$} \\
\end{cases}$

(Notice that the integrals for each of these four intervals are the same,
by symmetry.)

Answer (score 0):

Find the set $S \subseteq [0,2\pi]$ where $|x-\pi| < \cos^{-1}(\cos x)$.
Let $T = [0,2\pi] \setminus S$.
Then, the answer to your question is the sum $\int_S |x-\pi|dx + \int_T \cos^{-1}(\cos x) dx $

Answer (score 0):

well $min()$ means functions inside the argument of it which has minimum value in given interval for example if we are given $min(x,x^2)$ now if we want to see it's value from 0 to infinity it this function will be $x^2$ in $[0,1]$ and $x$ thereafter since $x^2 < x $ in $(0,1)$.